# Using a pivot table in rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables and using spatie/laravel-permission

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

I have a UserTable livewire component with mulitple columns however I now need to add the role assigned to the users listed in the table. The roles are handled by the spatie plugin.

For the pivot I have model_has_roles which is not in eloquent and I wish to get the name value from the roles table.

So the relationships:
model_has_roles.model_id => users.id
roles.is =>model_has_roles.role_id

I spent about an hour with chatGPT on this and it failed miserably.

So first how can i add a many to many relationship to get the role name using the user id and how do i then reference this as my column definition in rappasoft?

```
            Column::make('Role', 'roleName.name')
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable(),
```

and currently I have this in Users which is failing

```
    public function role()
    {
        $roleId = DB::table('model_has_roles')
            ->select('role_id')
            ->where('model_type', '=', 'App\Models\User')
            ->where('model_id', '=', $this->id)
            ->first()->role_id;

        $roleName = DB::table('roles')
            ->select('name')
            ->where('id', '=', $roleId)
            ->first()->name;

        return $roleName;
    }

    public function getRoleNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->role();
    }
```

last error is

```
Call to undefined relationship [roleName] on model [App\Models\User].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you create a ModelHasRole model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ModelHasRole extends Model
{}
```

Within user model, you define a role relationship:

```
public function role()
{
    $relation = $this->hasOneThrough(
        config('permission.models.role'),
        ModelHasRole::class,
       'model_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'role_id'
    );

    return $relation;
}
```

And then for your column definition in rappasoft

```
 Column::make('Role', 'role.name')
    ->sortable()
    ->searchable(),
```

**If rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables doesn't support hasOneThrough, try this way:**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ModelHasRole extends Model
{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(config('permission.models.role'));
    }
}
```

In user model:

```
public function modelHasRole()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\ModelHasRole', 'model');
}
```

And then for your column definition in rappasoft

```
 Column::make('Role', 'modelHasRole.role.name')
    ->sortable()
    ->searchable(),
```